# (FLUTTER 3.13) Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file.It's likely that this file was generated under E:\dev\build, but the tool couldn't find it

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx, android-app-bundle

i have problem when make signed aab file in flutter its give me error

`Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file. It's likely that this file was generated under E:\dev\build, but the tool couldn't find it. Process finished with exit code 1`

i have tried any method in stackoverflow but doesnt give any solution

Flutter 3.13.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 12fccda598 (2 weeks ago) • 2023-09-19 13:56:11 -0700
Engine • revision bd986c5ed2
Tools • Dart 3.1.2 • DevTools 2.25.0

additional information :
when i build other project in same device its can build normally without the warning message

I need answers and solution that can solve this error message. I have tried added flutter flavors still gave error message